# Magento 2 CSS files removed from theme/web directory after run setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2

I am getting a strange issue from the last few days, The issue is all the files and folders will be from "/app/design/frontend/Compnay_Name/Theme_Name/web" folder after running "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" command from SSH.

```
Below are the exact steps that I have done from SSH.
I first run below commands remove one directory from \app\code\Rootways for that I first go to this location in SSH then run below commands
 rm -r payment/

then run below commands from the website root directory
 php bin/magento s:up
 php bin/magento c:f
 php bin/magento c:c
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Can anyone suggest us how to find out this issue?

Comment: Which mode is there in your magento setup?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal developer